# How to know time that OSX was turned on programatically?

Tags: macos, datetime, operating-system

I dont find anything about this yet.
I need a program that save the time that the MAC was turned on and off. 
How do I do this in code? A Java or C++ solution would be preferred, but I will accept any.

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329443/proc-uptime-in-mac-os-x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282897/get-the-precise-time-of-system-bootup-on-ios-os-x

Comment: Thank youu @PetteriHietavirta . Now I just need to figure out how I will get the last time the user turned off. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the 'last' command which show you when the pc was rebooted etc..

see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7760/output-of-the-last-command